# Gallery won't center to page

Tags: css, centering

I am trying to center my gallery array. I tried:

- margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto 
  and
- margin:0 auto;
  and
  -text-align:center;

and have had no luck?

Here is the [link](http://rigstock.com/test_btc/gallery_2011.html)

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: It looks centered to me. Tried it in FF, IE and Chrome. Or am I just not looking at the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
#content ul {
padding: 0 0 16px 30px;
}
```

It is center aligned, but you've got left padding on the `ul` (30px)

Changing this to 0px will center align the gallery:

```
#content ul {
    padding: 0 0 16px 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what implications this will have on other elements, so perhaps create a second class just for the gallery:

```
#content ul.gallery {
    padding-left:0;
}
```